# Git Staging UI in IntelliJ (like in Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, git, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make the move from Eclipse to IntelliJ, but there's one thing that I miss from Eclipse that I can't seem to find in IntelliJ.

Eclipse has this Git Staging view that shows all the unstaged/staged changes and allows you to push commits as well. Of course you can right click to do git stuff in both Eclipse and IntelliJ, but for projects where you mostly just need to push changes, this is super convenient to have.

I haven't been able to find a nice UI like this in IntelliJ. Is there something I'm missing or does it not exist?

The only thing I've seen in IntelliJ is this, which I personally feel isn't as user-friendly to navigate.

[image]

For reference, this is the kind of thing I'm looking for (basically anything with an "unstaged changes" and "staged changes" and "commit" button will do):

[image]

Comment: There is an open feature request in the [IDEA issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63391).

Comment: got it, thanks. Too bad they haven't gotten around to it yet even though it's major priority :( I guess I'll use SourceTree to handle the git stuff for now